# Template abuse?

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic-cast

I wanted to transform the `dynamic_casts` from base class to derived from this style:

```
auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(object);
```

To something more compact. For that I have added in `Base` class the following template:

```
template<typename T>
T As() { return dynamic_cast<T>(this); }
```

So now the previous statement would be rewritten as

```
auto derived = object->As<Derived*>();
```

I like this style more. But I know there might be readability issues (subjective) or memory usage of the class maybe? If am I correct this will generate a function for each type of derived I cast. This number can be potentially large (100 different derived classes).

Should I just stick to plain `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: Did you check the possible code bloat? Nobody can predict it for sure, but such a small inline function in a header is unlikely to have any overhead compare to a direct dynamic cast..

Comment: Basically, this just gives a different name to `dynamic_cast<>`. It's generally not a good idea to wrap language keywords/operators/whatever into your own macros/functions/templates. Nevetheless, the lengths of the C++ cast keywords is a PITA, so I wouldn't blame you for using `->As<>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you read material from a number of experts who have participated in the design of C++ (Stroustrup, Sutter, the list goes on) you will find that `dynamic_cast`  (and all the `_cast`s) are verbose and clumsy for the programmer BY DESIGN.

Where at all possible, it is considered best to AVOID using them.    While all of the `_cast` operators have their place (i.e. there are circumstances in which they are genuinely the best solution to a problem) they are also blunt instruments that can be used to work around problems due to bad design.   Unfortunately, given a choice, a lot of programmers will reach for such blunt instruments rather than applying a bit more effort to learn appropriate techniques, and to clean up their design - which has benefits such as making the code easier to get working right, and easier to maintain.

`dynamic_cast` is, arguably, the worst of the `_cast` operators, since it almost invariably introduces an overhead at run time.    If it is used to work around deficiencies due to bad design, there is a distinct run-time penalty.

Making the syntax clumsy and verbose encourages a programmer to find alternatives (e.g. design types and operations on types, in a way that avoids the need for such conversions).

What you're asking for is a way to allow programmers to use `dynamic_cast` easily and with less thought.   That will encourage bad design, by allowing a programmer to easily use the `_cast` operators to work around design problems, when they would often be better off applying a bit more effort to avoid a need for such conversions in the first place.   There is plenty of information available about techniques that can be used to avoid use of operations like `dynamic_cast`.

So, yes, if you really need to use such conversions, I suggest you stick to use of `dynamic_cast`.

Better yet, you might want to also apply effort to learn design techniques and idioms that reduce how often you need to use it.